# For loop does not include all the strings inside the list

Tags: python

I am trying to randomly pick the player names and divide them into 2 different teams. My list has 5 names, however, the result only showed 4 names, and Team B is always having one player name only, while Team A always have 3 names. Can I know what is wrong with this and how do I fix it? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
from random import choice
teamA =[]
teamB =[]
players=['Campo', 'Elliston', 'Sarre', 'Priscilla', 'Josse']

def divide_player(team):
    for player in players:
        player_picked = choice(players)
        team.append(player_picked)
        players.remove(player_picked)

divide_player(teamA)
divide_player(teamB)
print(f'Team B: {teamB}')
print(f'Team A: {teamA}')
```

Here is the result:

```
Team B: ['Elliston']
Team A: ['Josse', 'Sarre', 'Campo']


Team B: ['Priscilla']
Team A: ['Josse', 'Sarre', 'Elliston']
```

Comment: You shouldn't remove items from a collection you are iterating over.

Comment: Part of your problem is that you are removing players from the `players` list. This changes the index and messes with your loop. If you don't have a reason to remove them in each loop, I wouldn't do it until the loop is done or even at all.

Comment: Also, how are you expecting to divide 5 players amongst two teams?

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do it is to `shuffle()` the players and split them into two teams:

```py
from random import shuffle

def divide_players(players):
    r = players[:]
    shuffle(r)
    return r[1::2], r[::2]

players = ['Campo', 'Elliston', 'Sarre', 'Priscilla', 'Josse']


teamA,teamB = divide_players(players)

print(f'Team B: {teamB}')
print(f'Team A: {teamA}')
```

Sample output:

```
Team B: ['Priscilla', 'Campo', 'Josse']
Team A: ['Sarre', 'Elliston']
```

Comment: lol, random is random . . .

Comment: Ok, code changed to align with reality (?)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:-

```
import random

players=['Campo', 'Elliston', 'Sarre', 'Priscilla', 'Josse']

def getPlayers(n):
    lp = []
    cp = players.copy()
    for _ in range(n):
        i = random.randint(0, len(cp)-1)
        lp.append(cp[i])
        cp.pop(i)
    return lp, cp

team_1, team_2 = getPlayers(3)

print(team_1)
print(team_2)
```

Comment: I think you should `return lp,cp`. That should save you from having to reconstitute `cp` outside the function.

Comment: Good point. I'll change it

Answer (score 0):

You should not mutate the list that you are already looping.
You can find many articles about this, ex: https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/fopp/TransformingSequences/WPDontMutateAListYouIterateThrough.html

How to solve it?
You should iterate over **copy** of the list. You can do this by

```
for x in list(players)
# or
for x in players[:]
```

Comment: You're giving all players to team A. How is team B supposed to have a chance now?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try this. Specify the number of player you want on the team and the players list:

```
from random import choice
players=['Campo', 'Elliston', 'Sarre', 'Priscilla', 'Josse']

def divide_player(num_of_players_wanted, players):
    if (num_of_players_wanted)>len(players):
        print('You wanted ', num_of_players_wanted,' players, but only ', len(players), ' are available')
        return None
    team=[]
    while (len(team)<num_of_players_wanted):    
        player_picked = choice(players)        
        if player_picked not in team:
            team.append(player_picked)
    return team

teamC=divide_player(7, players)
teamA=divide_player(3, players)
teamB=divide_player(4, players)
print(f'Team C: {teamC}')
print(f'Team A: {teamA}')
print(f'Team B: {teamB}')
```

result will be

```
You wanted  7  players, but only  5  are available
Team C: None
Team A: ['Josse', 'Sarre', 'Priscilla']
Team B: ['Elliston', 'Priscilla', 'Sarre', 'Josse']
```